# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make it filter spam?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my bot filter spam messages. Nothing too complex, just like *if someone sends more than 8 messages in 30 seconds, delete their most recent message*. How would I do so? I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not the same, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940721/cooldown-for-on-message-in-discord-py/65944105#65944105) question is pretty similar, with some tweaks you're gonna be able to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I know this is two months late but I though I would answer in case anyone else comes across this. You should look into the [Discord-Anti-Spam](http://Discord-Anti-Spam) package. It manages all of the spam detecting for you.