# command work every x seconds after being used by someone discord.py

Tags: python, discord, event-handling, discord.py

Im trying to make a bot with a on_message that works every 20 seconds after someone used it. For example if I write !hello the command can't be used by no one for 20 seconds.
Code that I started but I don't have clue how to finish it:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('hi')
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using the `on_message` event? It'd be much easier if you used a command

Comment: This is just an example, my bot is complex and there's a reason why im using on_message

Comment: it will be a pain to create a cooldown for each "command" you have in the `on_message` event, but you can take a look at one of my previous answers, [cooldown for on_message in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940721/cooldown-for-on-message-in-discord-py)

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this

```
#time in seconds.
@commands.cooldown(1, int(time), commands.cooldowns.BucketType.guild)
```

[Source](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107225/discord.ext.commands.cooldown)

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was searching for.

Comment: He's using the `on_message` event, the `commands.cooldown` decorator works only for commands @BuddyBoblll

Answer (score -1):

It seems like from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46095325/15073477) you can simply modify the standard `cooldown` effect to a whole `server`, instead of just `user`.

Ex.

```py
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.guild)
```

- 1 stands for one use
- 30 stands for 30 seconds
- for the last parameter you can use default, channel, or guild, to create a global, channel, or server ratelimit respectively

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was searching for.

Comment: If it helped, feel free to mark it as the correct answer for people who may want to reference it in the future.

Comment: He's using the `on_message` event, the `commands.cooldown` decorator works only for commands.

Comment: It seems like OP says it works, so I don't see a problem with it.