# Cooldown on on_message event discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a suggestion system with discord.py. A user DMs the bot a message and the bot sends that message in a specific channel. The code works, I wanted to understand if it is possible to add a cooldown in sending DMs to the bot and how to do it.

```
@client.event        
async def on_message(message):    
if not message.author.bot:
    if isinstance(message.channel, DMChannel):
        if len(message.content) > 700:
            await message.channel.send("Suggerimento troppo lungo")

        else:
            embedMod= discord.Embed(title="Suggerimento:", description=message.content, colour=0xfc5a50, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
            embedMod.set_footer(icon_url="https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.lnk.bio/profilepics/-1230732_20210524863.jpg")
            embedMod.set_author(name=f'{message.author}', icon_url=f'{message.author.avatar_url}')
            mod = client.get_channel(900085945414582312)
            await mod.send(embed=embedMod)
            await message.channel.send('Suggerimento registrato con successo, grazie mille.')
```

Update, is correct?

```
@client.event        # Suggerimenti
async def on_message(message):    
   bucket = cd_mapping.get_bucket(message)
   retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
   if retry_after:
      await message.channel.send("Scimmia")


   else:
       if not message.author.bot:
               if isinstance(message.channel, DMChannel):
                   if len(message.content) > 700:
                    await message.channel.send("Suggerimento troppo lungo")
            

              else:
                    embedMod= discord.Embed(title="Suggerimento:", description=message.content, colour=0xfc5a50, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
                   embedMod.set_footer(icon_url="https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.lnk.bio/profilepics/-1230732_20210524863.jpg")
                    embedMod.set_author(name=f'{message.author}', icon_url=f'{message.author.avatar_url}')
                    mod = client.get_channel(900085945414582312)
                    await mod.send(embed=embedMod)
                    await message.channel.send('Suggerimento registrato con successo, grazie mille.')
    else:    
                   await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cooldown for on\_message in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65940721/cooldown-for-on-message-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with **discord.py** cooldowns:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

cd_mapping = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    bucket = cd_mapping.get_bucket(message)
    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    if retry_after:
        # rate limited
    else:
        # not rate limited
```